# Trying to set a click listener to a recyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

I'm new to Android programming and trying to set a click listener to open another activity. The list loads fine, but when I click the items, nothing happens. This is my adapter:

```
public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(Product product);
}

private List<Product> productList;
private double currentLatitude, currentLongitude;
private Context context;
private final OnItemClickListener listener;

public AdapterForProducts(List<Product> productList, OnItemClickListener listener, double currentLatitude, double longitude, Context context){
    this.currentLatitude = currentLatitude;
    this.currentLongitude = longitude;
    this.productList = productList;
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_layout, parent, false);
    ViewHolderForProducts holder = new ViewHolderForProducts(view);
    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    //Use the provided View Holder on the onCreateViewHolder method to populate the current row on the RecyclerView
    ViewHolderForProducts holder = (ViewHolderForProducts) viewHolder;

    Product product = productList.get(position);
    String distanceText = "Distancia: " + round(distance(product.getLatitude(), product.getLongitude())) + " meters";
    holder.bind(productList.get(position), listener, distanceText);


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return productList.size();
}
```

the viewHolder:

```
public ViewHolderForProducts(View view){
    super(view);
    cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardView);
    name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
    value = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_value);
    distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.product_distance);
}



public void bind(final Product product, final AdapterForProducts.OnItemClickListener listener,
                 String distanceText) {
    name.setText(product.getName());
    value.setText("Preço: " + product.getValue());

    distance.setText(distanceText);

    itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(product);
        }
    });

}
```

And I'm calling it in the activity like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_and_show_product_list);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        latitude = extras.getDouble("latitude");
        longitude = extras.getDouble("longitude");
    }
    query = "";
    query_field = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.query_field);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchProductButton);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
    productList = new ArrayList<>();

    fillProductListByName();

    adapterForProducts = new AdapterForProducts(productList, new AdapterForProducts.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(Product product) {
            showProductOnMap(product);
        }
    }, latitude, longitude, getApplication());

    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterForProducts);
    adapterForProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            query = query_field.getText().toString();
            productList.clear();
            fillProductListByName();
            adapterForProducts.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
}
```

This is the list item xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:cardElevation="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:padding="16dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:text="Product Name"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_value"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_name"
            android:text="Price: " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_distance"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="51dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="51dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/product_value"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/product_value"
            android:text="Distance:" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. Apparently, this implementation doesn't work if there is some other clickable object inside the list item, as was the case with:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:padding="16dp">
```

All I did was to erase the android:clickable="true" from the RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

When you set the attr `android:clickable="true"` to the parent layout, its click method

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            listener.onItemClick(product);
        }
    });
```

will only be called if its childs doesn't have the `clickable = true` or have a `OnClickListener` set.

Actually, you don't need all these `android:clickable="true"`.

When you set `android:clickable="true"` you are setting a empty `ClickListener` to this view.

The click event is passed to the lowest view in the layout hierarchy with a ClickListener implemented, even with empty body. This is the cause of your bug, and its because of this that you have to remove the `android:clickable="true"`.
Removing the `android:clickable="true"`, removes the empty `ClickListener`, and now the lowest view in the layout hierarchy is the `CardView` with this ClickListener:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onItemClick(product);
            }
        });
```

So, this is the `ClickListener` that will be called.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'm having another problem with this code, maybe you can help me? I'm using this recycler view to show search results. In the same activity there's the view, an edittext and a search button, but for some reason the recycler only appears after I touch the edittext, when the keyboard appears. then when I search and the items change, it only appears again after the keyboard hides. Any clue to what might be happening? I'll post the code for the activity.